# How to convert .dicom (slices) to a single (volume) image?

Tags: dicom

I have 'n' number of slices, is it possible to convert them to a single file, (that has correct slice arrangement), and parse them using ImageIO or any other python package ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what ImageIO is, however for parsing a set of slices (which I assume you mean a single CT or MR type series, that's meant to be a single 3D volume) check out [simpleITK](https://pypi.org/project/SimpleITK/).

I think it will do exactly what you want: it's a very complete "3d aware" dicom library (and very fast as it's wrapped around C libraries).  In particular it will read a complete multi-file series, and create a single 3D representation of it.

It's representation is based on extended numpy objects - so in particular it will have a 3D numpy array for the series, but in addition knows about the 3D location/orientation of the series relative to the dicom patient coordinate system.

So once you have that, you've got all the spatial/3D info you need to be able to use with any other python libraries.

Comment: Thankyou so much, this is exactly what I am looking for!